# Proof by contradiction: Integers randomly ordered on rim of a disk

Tags: proof-verification, random, integers

(*I want to see whether this is a valid proof. It came up in the context of a book chapter on induction. I couldn't prove it using induction but found another way instead, which I'd like to check*)

**Problem**: All integers from 1 through 30 are painted in random order in the shape of a circle. We have to show that no matter what the order is, there must be three successive integers whose sum is at least 45.

**Proof**: Let us consider all of the possible sums of three successive integers. Starting at some arbitrary integer $i_1$ along the circle and moving clockwise where the second integer is $i_2$, the third $i_3$ etc...the first sum of three successive integers is $i_1 + i_2 + i_3$. The second sum is $i_2 + i_3 + i_4$, the third sum $i_3 + i_4 + i_5$, etc...for a total of $30$ sums.

Each integer along the circle will appear in $3$ of the $30$ sums of $3$ successive integers, meaning that the total of those $30$ sums of $3$ successive integers will be $3$ times the sum of the integers from $1$ through $30$, or $3 \cdot \frac{30 (31)}{2} = 1395$.

Now let's assume that none of the $30$ sums of $3$ successive integers is $\geq 45$; then the maximum total sum of those $30$ sums would be $30 \cdot 44 = 1320$.
But we know that the total sum of those $30$ sums of $3$ successive integers is $1395$, which means that the assumption that none of the sums is $\geq 45$ is wrong, and that at least one of the sums has to be $\geq 45$.

Comment: Looks right to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct, but you need not rely on proof by contradiction:  You have shown that the average of $30$ quantities is $46.5$.  Then you could simply use the fact that at least one quantity in any set must be at least the average of the quantities in the set.

Comment: Nicely thought of!

Comment: Indeed, very good point.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof seems right to me. If you do a similar reasoning, you can prove at least one sum is below $47$:

Assume no sum is either below $47$. Then those $30$ sums would add up to, at least, $1410 = 47\cdot30$, when we know the total sum is $1395$.

Comment: Thank you, I still can't believe I somehow managed to think this through.

Comment: What you prove is that there is a sum that is at most $46$.  Check this arrangement: $1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 13, 11, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 30, 28, 26, 24, 22, 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2$.  No sum is either $45$ or $46$.

Comment: @FabioSomenzi you are mostly right